# Filling in Proof: Well-definedness of depth(I,M).

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, homology-cohomology

From Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra with A View Toward Algebraic Geometry* (Theorem 17.4):

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module, where $R$ is Noetherian. If $$r= \min \{i : H^i(M\otimes K(x_1,\dots, x_n) ) \neq 0 \}, $$ then every maximal $M$-sequence in $I:=(x_1,\dots, x_n) \subseteq R$ has length $r$.

The proof in the text is as follows:

Let $y_1,\dots, y_s$ be a maximal $M$-sequence in $I$. By functoriality of the Koszul complex,
$$ H^{*}(M\otimes K(x_1,\dots, x_n,y_1,\dots, y_s)) \cong H^*(M\otimes K(x_1,\dots, x_n)) \otimes \wedge R^s $$
so that $r$ is also the smallest integer for which $H^{i}(M\otimes K(x_1,\dots, x_n,y_1,\dots, y_s)) \neq 0$. Since the cohomology does not vanish on some dimension, we cannot have $IM=M$. Using Corollary 17.12, $s=r$ as desired. $\square$

Here is Corollary 17.12:

> Suppose $x_1,\dots, x_i$ is a maximal $M$-sequence in $I=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$. The the Koszul cohomology vanishes on dimensions less than $i$, and if $IM\neq M$ then the $i$th dimensional cohomology does not vanish.

I understand every part of his proof, besides the last sentence. I just cannot figure out how he made that jump. I know there are other proofs of this fact, but I am not interested in those.

Comment: Do you know these properties: $M=IM\iff H_0({\bf x},M)=0$ and $H_i({\bf x,y};M)\simeq H_i({\bf y},M/{\bf x}M)$ if ${\bf x,y}$ is an $M$-sequence?

Comment: Yes, I do know those. Are you using the bold $x$ to denote $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ or are you just considering two elements $x,y$ in the ideal?

Comment: Yes, bold $x$ denotes a sequence.

Comment: Can anyone tell me in which part of the proof we need $M$ being a finitely generated $R$-module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One knows that $r=\min\{i:H_i({\bf x,y};M)\ne0\}$. Notice that $I=({\bf x,y})$. We also know that $I$ contains a maximal $M$-sequence, namely ${\bf y}$. If $IM\ne M$ then one can apply the Corollary 17.12 and get $s=\min\{i:H_i({\bf x,y};M)\ne0\}$, so $s=r$.

The only thing to show now is $IM\ne M$. Can you do this?

Comment: Wow - I cannot believe I overlooked that. That is embarrassingly simple - thank you so much. And to answer your question, yes. This is because $IM=M$ implies the Koszul homology vanishes in every dimension. Since by assumption the Koszul homology does not vanish in some dimension, the result follows.